# Is there any consensus on what is meant by Lagrange's equations of the first kind?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, conventions, definition

Is there any consensus on what is meant by *Lagrange's equations of the first kind?* [Joos and Freeman](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486652270.html)  define them as follows:

Coordinates are given in terms of a rectangular Cartesian coordinate system. Given a system of $N$ point-masses $\left\{ m_{\iota}\mathfrak{r_{\iota}}\right\} _{N},$ a set of $N$ corresponding forces $\left\{ \mathfrak{F}_{\iota}\right\} _{N}$ both indexed component-wise by $\left\{ i=1,2,\dots,3N\right\},$  a system of $K$ holonomous constrains $\left\{ f_{j}\left[\left\{ x_{i}\right\} _{3N}\right]=0\right\} _{K}$ and a set of $K$ provisionally undetermined real number constants $\left\{ \lambda_{j}\right\} _{K};$ *Lagrange's equations of the first kind* for this system are the $3N$ equations 
$$\left\{ m_{i}\ddot{x}_{i}=F_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{K}\lambda_{j}\frac{\partial f_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}\right\} _{3N}.$$

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) gives

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathfrak{r}_{\iota}}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\mathfrak{r}}_{\iota}}+\sum_{j=1}^{K}\lambda_{j}\frac{\partial f_{j}}{\partial\mathfrak{r}_{\iota}}=0$$

as *Lagrange's equations of the first kind*. Wells gives yet another definition of what he calls the *Lagrangian equations*, but does not distinguish between first and second kind.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17243/2451

Comment: The second is more general, when the $\mathfrak r_\iota$ are Cartesian coordinates and the force arises from a potential, the second reduces to the first.

Comment: Lagrange presumably historically defined his eqs. of 1st & 2nd kind in his publications. So what does he say?