# How to derive the Lagrangian for a system of first order equations of motion?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, computational-physics, variational-principle, complex-systems

Please be lenient if this question has been asked before in a similar manner. My background is in CS, but I am working on the physics-based modeling of complex systems and I am studying physics as an undergraduate.

I am studying a dynamical system that is **partially physical and partially complex (non-physical)**. For the purpose of this question, let us say that **the system is described by three states**: the spatial position $x$ and $y$, and money $m$, all measured at time $t$. You can think of a person who runs around and collects or throws money as he goes. This is not the real problem I am modeling, but it is a good enough approximation since the underlying mathematics is the same.

**I have a set of differential equations that describes the evolution over time of these three states**:

1. $\dot{x} = f(x)$
2. $\dot{y} = g(y)$
3. $\dot{m} = h(m)$ caveat: this might be a non-linear function of $x,y,m \to \dot{m} = h(m,x,y)$

These three equations were modeled in application of [1] on the basis of some datasets (synthetic, if it matters).

Under a hypothesis that derives from the literature and that we can challenge if necessary (but please assume that this is true for a second), **the evolution of the system is such that there exists an unknown Lagrangian** $L(x,y,m,\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{m},t)$ for which the associated action is stationary to first-order.
The corresponding Euler-Lagrangian equations should therefore be:

1. $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}}$
2. $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{y}}$
3. $\frac{\partial L}{\partial m} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{m}}$

Question 1: **How can I derive the possible forms of $L$ that satisfy the constraints that derive from the known equations of motion**? I am familiar with the method for deriving the equations of motion from a given Lagrangian in physical systems, as is commonly done in analytical mechanics, but I do not understand how to go the other way around. I understand that the Lagrangians that satisfy these constraints may be many, but it seems like not all possible functionals of these state variables will be Lagrangians: for me, **it is sufficient to identify one**, and ideally one with a few symbols, and discard some trivial cases. Since this is a problem that I will have to solve frequently in the future, I would like to have an idea on how to construct a Lagrangian given the equations of motion, in general, and not only in the application of this specific problem.

Question 2: This paper [2] estimates the polynomial representation of the Lagrangian that results in a minimised (not stationary) action given certain time series. If the Lagrangian can be approximated as a Taylor expansion, then this approach is reasonable. They do however make use of a control trajectory for which the action associated with the Lagrangian being approximated is not minimised, in order to avoid trivial trajectories (e.g. $\forall q,\dot{q}|L(q,\dot{q},t) = 1$). **Does the knowledge of a control trajectory help in answering question 1**? I have trajectories for which, by the same hypothesis deriving from the literature, the action should **not be stationary**, which means that those trajectories might provide further constraints on the shape of possible Lagrangians.

Please tell me if something is not clear or should be expressed better.

[1] Brunton, S. L., Proctor, J. L., & Kutz, J. N. (2016). Discovering governing equations from data by sparse identification of nonlinear dynamical systems. Proceedings of the national academy of sciences, 113(15), 3932-3937. https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1517384113

[2] Hills, D. J., Grütter, A. M., & Hudson, J. J. (2015). An algorithm for discovering Lagrangians automatically from data. PeerJ Computer Science, 1, e31. https://peerj.com/articles/cs-31.pdf

Edit: I had written $dt$ instead of $t$ in the first expression of $L$

Comment: My instinct is that it's not actually possible to get a first-order equation of motion from an action principle.  Roughly, if $\partial L/\partial \dot{q}$ depends on $\dot{q}$, then the term $d/dt( \partial L/\partial \dot{q})$ will involve second derivatives of $q$.  And if $\partial L/\partial \dot{q} = f(q)$ is independent of $\dot{q}$, then the Lagrangian must be of the form $\dot{q} f(q) + g(q)$;  in that case, the first term is a total derivative $d/dt(F(q))$, with $F$ an antiderivative of $f$, and so that term does not contribute to the Euler-Lagrange equations at all. ...

Comment: ... All of which is to say that I'd be interested to see where in the literature your hypothesis derives from, since it goes against my instincts (which could be wrong!)

Comment: This is reasonable, the time derivative of the partial derivative of L w.r.t. velocities will produce the second-order time derivative. I can add the knowledge on the second-order time derivatives of the state variables though, by approximating it numerically first and then regressing with the same technique indicated earlier for identifying $\dot{q_i}$. Would this be sufficient, in this case?

Comment: Related:  [Is there a universal algorithm that allows to find the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian, given any physical system that admits them?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695094/)

Comment: Are we allowed to use auxiliary variables? Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 and links therein.

Comment: If the equations of motion are second-order, then the other question I linked above would be pertinent.  That said, I would worry that you'd be over-fitting the data if you introduce $\ddot{q}$ as well; effectively you would be introducing an additional variable to your regression that might not have predictive power.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The problem discussed here in this post is a special instantiation of a general class of problems that are diffused in the behaviourist literature on social sciences. A variety of authors who have the roles of founding fathers in their respective branches of social sciences use the principle of least effort as the explanation for some observed characteristics of human behaviour. Google Scholar contains several of these: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=least+effort+human+behavior&btnG=&oq=least+effort+human

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The branch that interests me in particular has to do with the selection of paths by humans in long-distance mobility. A certain person claimed that the selection of paths follows the principle of least effort, and I am following up on the theoretical reasoning based upon that. I understand the difference between least effort and stationary action, it is still worth examining what are the margins of opportunity for applying analytical mechanics to human behaviour, provided that this can be treated as deterministic.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v4): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: The laziest way to do it is introduce new dynamical variables $u,\,v,\,w$ with $L$ equal up to total derivatives to $u(f-\dot{x})+v(g-\dot{y})+w(h-\dot{m})$, e.g. $L=uf+\dot{u}x+vg+\dot{v}y+wh+\dot{w}m$.

Comment: My assessment is that this line of investigation will turn out to be a blind alley. I grant It may be possible to find meaningful application of some of the mathematical *tools* of mechanics in models of human behavior. I expect: if such applicability exists it will not involve connection between what you refer to as least effort and Hamilton's stationary action. To see why: There is a discussion by me of [Hamilton's stationary action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670705/17198) here on physics stackexchange. The key points are visualized with diagrams.

Comment: Hello @Cleonis :) We have met in another life and another social network, I will send you a message from that other website shortly. I am familiar with your website, I did not know you also frequented this community.
The consideration that Lagrangian mechanics applies to human systems is not mine, but there is some research going in that direction (maybe unfruitful, ultimately). An example is this: 
SANDLER, U. (2020). GENERALIZED LAGRANGIAN APPROACH AND BEHAVIOR OF LIVING SYSTEMS. American Academic Press. 
I read the book (chapter 5-6), and I would like to understand if it is valid

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is your problem ?.

with the non holonomic constraint equations

$$\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\dot x}-f \left( x \right) 
\\ {\dot y}-g \left( y \right) \\ 
{\dot m}-h \left( m,x,y \right) \end {array} \right]
=\vec  0$$

and the kinetic energy

$$T=\frac 12\,(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot m^2)$$

you can obtain with EL the equations of motion

$$\ddot x=\left( {\frac {d}{dx}}f \left( x \right)  \right) {\dot x}\\
\ddot y=\left( {\frac {d}{dy}}g \left( y \right)  \right) {\ddot y}\\
\ddot m=\left( {\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}h \left( m,x,y \right) 
 \right) {\dot x}+ \left( {\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}h \left( m,x,
y \right)  \right) {\dot y}+ \left( {\frac {\partial }{\partial m}}h
 \left( m,x,y \right)  \right) {\dot m}
$$

Comment: it is not a physical system, so I cannot assume that the lagrangian corresponds to T-V. The problem is exactly that I do not know the analytical expression of the Lagrangian, though I know the equations of motion and I would like to learn the former on the basis of the latter. Previous comments indicate that this corresponds to the [Inverse problem for Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics), with which I'm trying to get familiar