# Doubts about "whether a given system has a Lagrangian" and "inverse problem of the calculus of variations"

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

There has been extensive discussion in the literature and on this forum regarding the question of "**whether a given system has a Lagrangian**"  (e.g. [post1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357775/289541), [post2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/), [post3](https://mathoverflow.net/q/101395/), and [paper1](https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/40/33/010), [paper2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.difgeo.2016.01.005)).

The fundamental approach involves framing this question as the "**inverse problem of the calculus of variations**", wherein, given a set of second-order differential equations, one seeks the necessary and sufficient conditions for transforming them into the Euler-Lagrange equations. The results of this approach can be found on various platforms, including [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics#Douglas.27_theorem_and_the_Helmholtz_conditions).

However, I still harbor doubts about the underlying premise of this approach. Our understanding of a system may not necessarily begin with its differential equations; rather, we might only be aware of the components of the system (particles, interactions, etc., similar to the positive problem). From this perspective, there seems to be a gap between the question of "whether a given system has a Lagrangian" and the "inverse problem of the calculus of variations."

How can we address this gap?

Comment: One of the papers you linked to is also available on arxiv.org: D.M. Gitman, V.G. Kupriyanov, [On the action principle for a system of differential equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.4532) (The reason for mentioning that: the link you gave is to a repository with a paywall)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Briefly speaking OP's question seems to be: *Given a physical system, how to model it and find the equations of motion?* That's a good but broad question whose answer presumably depends on the circumstances. However, ideally speaking$^1$, once the [equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) are known, it then becomes [the inverse problem for Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics).

---

$^1$It should perhaps be mentioned that model building in modern theoretical  physics (say e.g. beyond the standard model) often takes the opposite route: Start with an action principle respecting certain symmetries and properties, and then work out the equations of motion.

Comment: 1. Does the term "opposite route" here already imply the assumption that the system has a Lagrangian (and thus an action can be formulated)? 2. So, if we want to determine whether a system has a Lagrangian, we either need to start from its equations of motion by solving the inverse problem, or directly formulate the Lagrangian based on specific circumstances. Is this statement accurate?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It could be a mix/hybrid/combination thereof.