# Counterexamples to the least action principle

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, friction, variational-principle, action, dissipation

Many of important equations in physics satisfy the least action principle, namely they are Euler-Lagrange equations for some Lagrangian. On the other hand it is known in mathematics that not all differential equations (both ODE and PDE) are Euler-Lagrange.

> Are there physically important (!) equations which are not Euler-Lagrange?

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Are you asking generally about equations that cannot be written in terms of an action principle or about equations that a physicist might expect or hope to be able to write in terms of an action principle but can't? (I would guess the latter, as I expect the former has many 'trivial' examples)

Comment: @BySymmetry I am asking about equations about which it is known or expected that they cannot be written in terms of action principle. But also I would interested in examples when such an interpretation is unknown although it is expected.

Answer (score 3):

"Physically important" depends on who you ask, but Type IIB supergravity theory in 10 dimensions does not have a simple action principle that is Lorentz-invariant.  The standard reference for this is

> Neil Marcus & John H. Schwarz, "Field theories that have no manifestly Lorentz-invariant formulation." Physics Letters **B115**, 111–114 (1982).

However, it is possible to construct an action for this theory by introducing auxiliary fields and/or breaking Lorentz invariance.  See the following reference for more details and some historical references:

> Ashoke Sen, ["Covariant action for type IIB supergravity."](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FJHEP07%282016%29017)  Journal of High Energy Physics 2016:17 (2016).