# Lagrangian via equation of the motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

If I have a lagrangian, then I can get the equations of the motion using the Euler-Lagrange equations. My question is about the converse of this statement: If one knows the equations of motion, like $=0$ and $2″+32=0$, then how to derive the lagrangian (or equivalent lagrangians)? By $(x,y)$, I mean, generalized coordinates $q:=(x,y)$.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3555370/11127 Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Sometimes if you're lucky, Wolfram Alpha will find a possible Lagrangian, when you enter a PDE or ODE