# Does the principle of stationary action always work?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

Give some Lagrangian we use the principle of stationary action to find the desired euqations of motion for something (e.g. a field).

A lot of modern physics seems to be based on the principle of stationary action. I read it works for classical mechanics, general relativity, Quantum chromodynamics, quantum electrodynamics, weak interactions and more stuff.

However, is there a field where the principle of stationary action does not yield the desired result or where it fails (contradicts some experimental result)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3500/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20188/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks, very intersseting stuff. My search earlier was not as helpful.