# Must there exist a Lagrangian for any 2nd order ordinary derivative equation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

We know if there exist a Lagrangian of some ODE, then it must exist many equivalent Lagrangian.

My question:

Then must there exist a Lagrangian for any 2nd order ODE? If not, do we have some necessary or sufficient conditions for a dynamical system which can be described by some Lagrangian?

Comment: This is very related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333379/

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20188/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3500/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 and links therein.