# Quantum field theory not related to classical field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, classical-field-theory, quantization

**Overvation 1**: Whatever quantization process is used, it is common to define a QFT from a classical field theory.

**Observation 2**: On the other hand, given a lagrangian QFT, one could try to "classicalize" the theory by transforming operator valued fields into classical field having the right Poisson bracket relations.

My questions are the following:

1. A priori, the "classifying process" for lagrangian QFTs described in the second observation is not possible for any field theory, is it ? Is there an obvious class of lagrangian QFTs for which it is not possible ?
2. Now if we drop down the lagrangian requirement one could ask first, are there some QFTs that are defined in other ways than with their lagrangian ? If so, I suppose that finding if they are lagrangian or not can be troublesome.
3. Are there some QFTs that are proved to be non-lagrangian QFTs ? How are they then defined ?

Comment: A physically relevant quantum theory should obey the [correspondence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do "typical" QFT's lack a lagrangian description?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163073/)