# Order of product of $x$ and $p$ while deriving Hamiltonian from a Lagrangian in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, quantization

Everyone who has taken a course in Quantum Mechanics has at some point derived a quantum Hamiltonian from a Lagrangian. However, I can't seem to find any reference on the topic.
My question is regarding the product $p_i x_i$ in the Legendre transform:
$$H = \sum_i p_i \dot x_i - KE+ PE.\tag{1}$$
Is this the correct order or does the order not matter? At what point does one make the upgrade from classical variables to quantum variables and introduce the commutation relations?

Comment: Actually (at least in my perception) this is pretty rare. Quantum Mechanics (at least introductory) doesn't even mention Lagrangians. What often happens is that a classical lagrangian is legendre transformed to yield a classical hamiltonian (which then can be used in QM). Instead of postulating a lagrangian and using it, you could as well just use a hamiltonian from the start.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp You are correct! Except in some cases where the intuition fails, it is a good idea to start from the lagrangian and then follow the prescription to get the Hamiltonaian.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, one quantizes a theory in the following order:

$$\begin{align} \text{classical}& \text{ Lagrangian} \cr
\downarrow&\text{ Legendre transformation} \cr 
\text{classical}& \text{ Hamiltonian}\cr
\downarrow&\text{ quantization} \cr
\text{quantum}& \text{ Hamiltonian}\end{align}\tag{I}$$

see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57299/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389944/2451) Phys.SE posts.

However, OP apparently wants to quantize in the opposite order:

$$\begin{align} \text{classical}& \text{ Lagrangian} \cr
\downarrow&\text{ quantization ??} \cr
\text{quantum}& \text{ Lagrangian ??}\cr
\downarrow&\text{ quantum Legendre transformation ??} \cr 
\text{quantum}& \text{ Hamiltonian}\end{align}\tag{II}$$

There are several issues with OP's proposal (II) before one could address OP's question about a quantum Legendre transformation: E.g. how do we define [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) using only Lagrangian variables $q$ and $v$? Of course, one could in principle work backwards using the conventional method (I).

OP's eq. (1) has related issues, as OP already seems to be aware of: How should one order the $p\dot{q}$ term to ensure that the quantum Hamiltonian is Hermitian? It seems easier to just use the conventional quantization scheme (I).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see what you mean about commutation relations. However, there has to be a more formal way to do everything in terms of quantized coordinates and momenta. I will keep looking.