# Is It Possible to Express all fundamental forces in the form of generalized potentials?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, variational-principle

I have Started reading Hamilton's Principle or Principle of Least Action In first course of Undergraduate classical mechanics.
So, I think it becomes easier to apply the Variational principles if forces can be expressed as generalized potentials.

So my first question was,
$ Is\ it\ possible\ to\ express\ all\ Fundamental\ Forces\ in\ nature\ in\ the\ form\ of\ \\ generalized\ potentials\ ?                   $

The Question seems very objective with YES/NO Answer. But this is not my intention.

I am hoping for some detailed answer. If you can't then why? and what are further insightful consequences.

Comment: I have never seen weak or strong interaction been formulated in classical-mechanical framework, yet your tabs suggest you are asking only about classical systems. So what exactly do you mean by fundamental forces, and do you really wish your answer to be restricted to classical mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3500/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20298/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I don't keep it restricted to the classical mechanics, I have Just mentioned that that to tell you about my background, so that It helps to formulate good answer